# Wpf application gets installed each time I click desktop icon

Tags: wpf

I am creating wpf application,in a setup I have given some path where my application'll get install.Once get installed I am running Application via post build event.after application when application run for first time I am adding security logic to the folder where my application gets installed using CLSID(which changes the actual path of folder, and it wont accessible). Up till now everything is fine, but when I click on desktop icon to run application, it again installs and created folder with same data on the same location.Now I have two folders one with security and other w/o. I know why it is happening, it is because the default installation folder is changes via CLSID and application not able to find the default location.How can I avoid happening so? Please help me

Comment: Perhaps the security changes to the folder prevents the application to run? What have you changed exactly?

Comment: Hi Ralf de Kleine, thanks for your reply.
Actually I have applied CLSID to the folder on my drive so that to prevent access to the folder, hence folder path get changed(encrypted) and not able to load when application runs